# FirebaseCrash: Failed to initialize crash reporting

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

I am getting following error in my logcat while trying to use Firebase Crash Reporting:

```
FirebaseCrash: Failed to initialize crash reporting

FirebaseCrash: com.google.firebase.crash.internal.zzg$zza: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzsb$zza: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
```

I have added the following in module app project and build gradle:

```
   classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
   compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0'
   compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.4.0'
   compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.4.0`

   apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and added `google-services.json` in the app folder.

I got the Firebase Analytics working after the 24 hours, time limit for first updates. For getting the first error I have added in `MainCctivity`.

```
FirebaseCrash.report(new Exception("My first Android non-fatal error"));
```

The Google Play Services I use is version 9.4.52(238-127739847) in my emulator (Nexus Api 23, Android Version 6.0). Still the  error is shown in logcat , how can I get the crash report working?

Comment: Could you confirm that the device is using the latest version of Google Play services? Having an old version of Google Play services can sometimes be the cause.

Comment: Google Play Services I use is version 9.4.52

Comment: Are you trying to add crash reporting to an existing app, or are you starting from scratch with a whole new, minimal app that does nothing but try to send the report?  If you haven't tried doing a minimal app, let's try that first?

Comment: I have connected my admob account with firebase and followed thise steps, not a new app

Comment: Could you try this sample then: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/crash to help narrow down where the issue is. If the issue still exists then you should make a report to firebase support at firebase.google.com/support

Comment: Thanks for the help, Arthur and Doug, The problem might be i was testing on emulator, where play store app on my emulator was not logged in to google play account, when tested on real device its working fine, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

The bottom line here is that Firebase Crash Reporting only works on devices with Google Play services, and that its version needs to match or exceed the Firebase client library version.

If you are running in an emulator, you need to use an image with Play services installed.